# Arithmetic overflow in appendix section with metropolis beamer

Tags: beamer, appendix, beamer-metropolis

I want to create `beamer` presentation with a `metropolis` theme and progress bar option. And I also need to add an section in the appendix, therefore I add the package `appendixnumberbeamer` to avoid to increment the progress bar in the appendix. Then, when I compile I get an `arithmetic overflow error`. This error is pointing the section in the appendix.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

    \usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer} % appendix
    \usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis} % Metropolis Theme
        % Set size to make thing easier to see
        \makeatletter
            \setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{1ex}
            \setlength{\metropolis@progressonsectionpage@linewidth}{1ex}
        \makeatother
        
    % Presentation information
    \title{Title of the presentation}
    \date{\today}
    \author{John DOE}
    \institute{My Institute}

\begin{document}
        % FRAME
        \begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
            \titlepage  
        \end{frame}
    
    \section{First section}
    
        % FRAME
        \begin{frame}{Slide title}
            Last slide before the appendix
        \end{frame}
    
    \appendix

    \section{Here comes the problems}
        
        % FRAME
        \begin{frame}
            Something that is in a section within the appendix
        \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

I assume the problem comes from a division by zero or something of this kind. So how to resolve properly this issue ?

Comment: It disappears after a second run, have you tried compiling multiple times with commenting out and uncommenting the `\section{Here comes the problems}`?

Comment: @AboAmmar I agree, it disappear after the second compilation. But it is avoidable directly from the first compilation ? Because I used a script that stop if there is errors !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not actively using the `\appendixtotalframenumber`, so maybe you could avoid the error on the first compilation with this quick hack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

    \usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer} % appendix
    \gdef\appendixtotalframenumber{1}
    
    \usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
        % Set size to make thing easier to see
        \makeatletter
            \setlength{\moloch@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{1ex}
            \setlength{\moloch@progressonsectionpage@linewidth}{1ex}
        \makeatother
        
    % Presentation information
    \title{Title of the presentation}
    \date{\today}
    \author{John DOE}
    \institute{My Institute}

\begin{document}
        % FRAME
        \begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
            \titlepage  
        \end{frame}
    
    \section{First section}
    
        % FRAME
        \begin{frame}{Slide title}
            Last slide before the appendix
        \end{frame}
    
    \appendix

    \section{Here comes the problems}
        
        % FRAME
        \begin{frame}
            Something that is in a section within the appendix
        \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```